# How to fix GPA output for Student Records Program

Tags: c++

In my previous post, I needed help on some code for a program I was writing that would output data from a .txt file with each student's ID, Name, Course, Credits, Scores, and GPA.

StudentRecords.txt

```
12546 Amy   CS1 4 81 
13455 Bill  CS1 4 76
14328 Jim   CS1 4 64
14388 Henry CS3 3 80
15667 Peter CS3 3 45
12546 Amy   CS2 4 90 
13455 Bill  CS2 4 85
14328 Jim   CS2 4 71

12546 Amy   CS3 3 90 
13455 Bill  CS3 3 75
14328 Jim   CS3 3 69
```

The following table was used to calculate the GPA(just a reference):

```
Range Grade:
90 -- 100 > 4.0
80 -- 89 > 3.0
70 -- 79 > 2.0
60 -- 69 > 1.0
0 -- 59 > 0.0
```

I was advised to use vectors instead of using arrays. So I rewrote my program.

I was able to output each student's ID, Name, Course, Credits, and Scores in a organized data structure. However, my GPA is not correct for each student.

I have tried to multiply `int grade` with both `denominator += records[i].Courses[j].Credit;` and `numerator += records[i].Courses[j].Credit;` , but it didn't work out.

If anyone can help me out on this, I would appreciate it!

My Current Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Course
{
    string CourseName;
    int Credit;
    int Score;
};

struct Student
{
    int ID;
    string Name;
    vector<Course> Courses;
};

int locateStudent(int id, vector<Student> records);

int main()
{
    fstream inputFile;
    string fileName = "StudentRecords.txt";
    inputFile.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);

    int stuList;
    int uniqueID;
    Course tempCourse;

    string name;
    string courseNm;
    int credit;
    int score;

    vector<Student> records;

        if (inputFile.is_open())
        {
            while(!inputFile.eof())
            {
                inputFile >> uniqueID;
                stuList = locateStudent(uniqueID, records);

                if (stuList == -1)
                {
                    Student tempSt;
                    tempSt.ID = uniqueID;
                    inputFile >> tempSt.Name >> courseNm >> credit >> score;
                    tempCourse = {courseNm, credit, score};

                    tempSt.Courses.push_back(tempCourse);
                    records.push_back(tempSt);
                }
                else
                {
                    inputFile >> name;
                    inputFile >> courseNm >> credit >> score;
                    tempCourse = {courseNm, credit, score};
                    records[stuList].Courses.push_back(tempCourse);
                }
            }
            inputFile.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "File cannot be opened.";
        }


        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << records[i].ID << "\n" << records[i].Name << "\n";
            cout << "==========\n";

            int numerator = 0;
            int denominator = 0;
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < records[i].Courses.size(); j++)
            {
                int curScore = records[i].Courses[j].Score;
                cout << records[i].Courses[j].CourseName << "  ";
                cout << records[i].Courses[j].Credit << "  ";
                int grade = curScore == 100 ? 4 : (curScore);
                cout << grade << "\n";

                numerator += records[i].Courses[j].Credit;
                denominator += records[i].Courses[j].Credit;
            }

            cout << "==========\n";
            cout << "GPA: " << (double)numerator / denominator << "\n\n";
        }
}

int locateStudent(int uniqueID, vector<Student> records)
{
    int curID;
    for (unsigned int check = 0; check < records.size(); check++)
    {
        curID = records[check].ID;
        if (uniqueID == curID)
        {
            return check;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

My Current Output:

```
12546
Amy
==========
CS1  4  81
CS2  4  90
CS3  3  90
==========
GPA: 1

13455
Bill
==========
CS1  4  76
CS2  4  85
CS3  3  75
==========
GPA: 1

14328
Jim
==========
CS1  4  64
CS2  4  71
CS3  3  69
==========
GPA: 1

14388
Henry
==========
CS3  3  80
==========
GPA: 1

15667
Peter
==========
CS3  3  45
==========
GPA: 1
```

Expected Output:

```
12546
Amy
==========
CS1  4  81
CS2  4  90
CS3  3  90
==========
GPA: 3.64

13455
Bill
==========
CS1  4  76
CS2  4  85
CS3  3  75
==========
GPA: 2.36

14328
Jim
==========
CS1  4  64
CS2  4  71
CS3  3  69
==========
GPA: 1.36

14388
Henry
==========
CS3  3  80
==========
GPA: 3

15667
Peter
==========
CS3  3  45
==========
GPA: 0
```

Comment: I suggest that you write a function `float calculateGPA(Student s)`. This will help you focus on just this one operation as well as give a smaller piece of code to illustrate what you are struggling with.

Comment: Can you calculate Amy's GPA by hand? How do you get `3.64` from her grades and number of credits for each class?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compute a weighted average, where the weights are the credits. The denominator is right : it is the sum of all the weights. However, the numerator is wrong : it should be the sum of each score multiplied by its corresponding weight.

This will give you a mean score between 0 and 100 (since all scores belong to this range) ; so at the end you'll have to scale it down so it lies between 0 and 4 (the value range of the GPA).

The resulting code is as follows :

```cpp
int numerator = 0;
int denominator = 0;
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < records[i].Courses.size(); j++)
{
    int curScore = records[i].Courses[j].Score;
    int curCredit = records[i].Courses[j].Credit;
    cout << records[i].Courses[j].CourseName << "  ";
    cout << curCredit << "  ";
    cout << curScore << "\n";

    numerator += curScore * curCredit;
    denominator += curCredit;
}

cout << "==========\n";
cout << "GPA: " << (double)numerator / denominator / 25.0 << "\n\n";
```

Comment: Note that I have removed this `int grade = curScore == 100 ? 4 : (curScore);` line : it seems you had figured you had to scale the scores down but did not know how to do it, since this will only affect the maximum score and not any other lower score.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Thank you @Code-Apprentice for your help! I written the `float mapGPA (int Score)` function that would help calculate my GPA along with adding the header file `#include <iomanip>` in order to arrange the decimal for the GPA.

My Updated Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct Course
{
    string CourseName;
    int Credit;
    int Score;
};

struct Student
{
    int ID;
    string Name;
    vector<Course> Courses;
};

float mapGPA (int Score)
{
    if (Score < 60)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (Score < 70)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (Score < 80)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (Score < 90)
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else if (Score <= 100)
    {
        return 4;
    }

    return 0;
}

int locateStudent(int id, vector<Student> records);

int main()
{
    fstream inputFile;
    string fileName = "StudentRecords.txt";
    inputFile.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);

    int stList;
    int uniqueID;
    Course tempCourse;

    string name;
    string courseNm;
    int credit;
    int score;

    vector<Student> records;

        if (inputFile.is_open())
        {
            while(!inputFile.eof())
            {
                inputFile >> uniqueID;
                stList = locateStudent(uniqueID, records);

                if (stList == -1)
                {
                    Student tempSt;
                    tempSt.ID = uniqueID;
                    inputFile >> tempSt.Name >> courseNm >> credit >> score;
                    tempCourse = {courseNm, credit, score};

                    tempSt.Courses.push_back(tempCourse);
                    records.push_back(tempSt);
                }
                else
                {
                    inputFile >> name;
                    inputFile >> courseNm >> credit >> score;
                    tempCourse = {courseNm, credit, score};
                    records[stList].Courses.push_back(tempCourse);
                }
            }
            inputFile.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "File cannot be opened.";
        }


        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << records[i].ID << "\n" << records[i].Name << "\n";
            cout << "==========\n";

            int numerator = 0;
            int denominator = 0;
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < records[i].Courses.size(); j++)
            {
                int curScore = records[i].Courses[j].Score;
                cout << records[i].Courses[j].CourseName << "  ";
                cout << records[i].Courses[j].Credit << "  ";
                int curGrade = curScore == 100 ? 4 : (curScore);
                cout << curGrade << "\n";

                cout << setprecision(3);
                numerator += records[i].Courses[j].Credit * mapGPA(curScore);
                denominator += records[i].Courses[j].Credit;
            }

            cout << "==========\n";
            cout << "GPA: " << (double)numerator / denominator << "\n\n";
        }
}

int locateStudent(int uniqueID, vector<Student> records)
{
    int curID;
    for (unsigned int check = 0; check < records.size(); check++)
    {
        curID = records[check].ID;
        if (uniqueID == curID)
        {
            return check;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

My Updated Output:

```
12546
Amy
==========
CS1  4  81
CS2  4  90
CS3  3  90
==========
GPA: 3.64

13455
Bill
==========
CS1  4  76
CS2  4  85
CS3  3  75
==========
GPA: 2.36

14328
Jim
==========
CS1  4  64
CS2  4  71
CS3  3  69
==========
GPA: 1.36

14388
Henry
==========
CS3  3  80
==========
GPA: 3

15667
Peter
==========
CS3  3  45
==========
GPA: 0
```